# Why can't I surface plot a big data set of 1000x20?

Tags: matlab, dataset, surface

I'm testing out an algorithm and saved a dataset with 100x20 values that I successfully import as a matrix in Matlab and plot it using the surface command. That plot looks like.

[image]

Then I do the exact same thing but for a data set with 10 times the values on the y-axis (a 1000x20 matrix). This results in following picture, where the black rectangle are z-values seemingly at 0 rendered:

[image]

It's the exact same test so the same values should still exist, for the 0-100 part of the y-axis. The values look like they were imported correctly in the table before plotting but why does the surface plot look completely wrong?

There not much code... All i type is
`x=data(1, 2:end)` 
`y=data(2:end, 1)` 
`test=data(2:end, 2:end)`
and `surface(x,y, test)` 
where *test* is the imported matrix using drag and drop to matlab and *x*, *y* are just simple vectors with correct dimensions since `surface` complains otherwhise.

---

looking through the table, there are no irregularities and using `max` and `min` shows nothing strange either:

[image]

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong without any code

Comment: There is no code really... just `surface(x,y, test)` where _test_ is the imported table using drag and drop to matlab and x, y are just simple vectors with correct dimensions to 1000 and 10 000. Which can be seen in the figure that they are represented correctly.

Comment: The values of your matrices must be different. The first plot has z values around 10^5, but the second one has significantly smaller values. I think you need to check you data, or show the code, otherwise it's impossible to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Alright, added some more to the question. The data set is way too big to show the table itself.

Comment: @Jakkarn, the `1.3732e4` value is suspicious (and corresponds to the peak in the surface), given the other relatively small max values. Plot a histogram of the data `hist(test(:),100)` and see if you have an outlier.

Comment: I would argue that `max` does show something strange.  First, note that there is a multiplier of `1.0e+04` before the rest of the answer.  Second, note that the max of column 18 is much larger than the others.

Comment: It was me missing that number although I checked several times (probably stressed at that time). Didn't have time before but thought I should give some cred since @kmac found the problem. Like jeff irwin said as well.